# What do I do when generating a controller for an irregular noun?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controller

I have a model called legacy and now I am looking to generate the controller for it. Will rails get confused by a controller named legacies? Are there any potential issues down to road with these naming conventions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails uses a module called [**Inflector**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html) to convert singular names to plurals , cameilize and similar tasks. The module for example automatically map a `person` model to a `people` controller.

You can add a new [irregular](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections.html#method-i-irregular) rule for rails to pickup by adding in your `config/initilizers/inflections.rb` :

```
#Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file

ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'legacy', 'legacies'
end
```

## Update

You can find the rules shiped with rails at: (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflections.rb) which aren't so many although there were a lot of pull_requests to add new rules but Rails core team decided the following:

> The Rails core team has stated patches for the inflections library
>   will not be accepted in order to avoid breaking legacy applications
>   which may be relying on errant inflections. If you discover an
>   incorrect inflection and require it for your application, you’ll need
>   to correct it yourself.

Comment: Can I see which words are already done automatically, if so where would I check? That way I don't have to add legacy if not needed...